# OR clause in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I get **(A || B) && ( C || D)** query in Rails 5 ActiveRecord?. I tried
 `Post.where(a).or(Post.where(b)).where(c).or(Post.where(d))`

but It produces as: **(A || B) && C || D**. What would be the correct code to get desired query?

Comment: Did you find a solution that you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

The Rails `or()` method is not as complex as this. There is a long discussion about the feature when it was first proposed [here, on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052)

This method is meant to provide a convenient way of Railsifying queries, but sometimes, things just cannot be that simple. The `or()` method essentially is stuck with reading left-to-right.

Your best bet while sticking to a "Railsy" convention would be to follow one of the following approaches:

```
Post.where("a OR b").where("c OR d")             # Example 1 - SQL with additional where()
Post.where(a: [true, !b]).where(c: [true, !d])   # Example 2 - Array comparison
Post.where("(a OR b) AND (c OR d)")              # Example 3 - SQL only
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pushing each of the `or` queries down into individual named scopes in the `Post` model?  For me, splitting them out yielded different results.  Try something like the code below and see if you get the expected results (I didn't have a Rails app handy so I put everything into a single Ruby file):

**rails_where_or.rb**

```
require 'active_record'
require 'rspec'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :posts do |t|
    t.boolean :a, default: false
    t.boolean :b, default: false
    t.boolean :c, default: false
    t.boolean :d, default: false
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.a_or_b_and_c_or_d
    a_or_b.c_or_d
  end

  def self.a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained
    where(a: true).or(where(b: true)).
      where(c: true).or(where(d: true))
  end

  def self.a_or_b
    where(a: true).or(where(b: true))
  end

  def self.c_or_d
    where(c: true).or(where(d: true))
  end
end

RSpec.describe Post do
  let!(:only_a) do
    described_class.create!(a: true)
  end
  let!(:only_b) do
    described_class.create!(b: true)
  end
  let!(:only_c) do
    described_class.create!(c: true)
  end
  let!(:only_d) do
    described_class.create!(d: true)
  end
  let!(:a_and_b) do
    described_class.create!(a: true, b: true)
  end
  let!(:a_and_c) do
    described_class.create!(a: true, c: true)
  end
  let!(:a_and_d) do
    described_class.create!(a: true, d: true)
  end
  let!(:b_and_c) do
    described_class.create!(b: true, c: true)
  end
  let!(:b_and_d) do
    described_class.create!(b: true, d: true)
  end
  let!(:c_and_d) do
    described_class.create!(c: true, d: true)
  end

  describe '.a_or_b_and_c_or_d' do
    let(:a_or_b_and_c_or_d) do
      described_class.a_or_b_and_c_or_d
    end

    it 'returns only records that match (A || B) && ( C || D )' do
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(only_a)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(only_b)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(only_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(only_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(a_and_b)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).not_to include(c_and_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).to include(a_and_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).to include(a_and_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).to include(b_and_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d).to include(b_and_d)
    end
  end

  describe '.a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained' do
    let(:a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained) do
      described_class.a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained
    end

    it 'returns records that match (A || B) && C || D ' do
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).not_to include(only_a)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).not_to include(only_b)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).not_to include(only_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).not_to include(a_and_b)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(only_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(c_and_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(a_and_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(a_and_d)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(b_and_c)
      expect(a_or_b_and_c_or_d_all_chained).to include(b_and_d)
    end
  end
end
```